# Creating ListView which contains Layout

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to create a ListView which contains a RelativeLayout which contains an ImageView and another Layout (Linear). Linear Layout Contains some TextView.

How can I create this ListView??

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Do you mean each row would be a RelativeLayout such as you describe?  If so, then it would be easy.  Have you looked at the `ListAdapter` and `BaseAdapter` classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a layout for the rows. Let's say the ImageView is `R.id.image` an the TextView `R.id.text`. The row layout is `R.id.row_layout`
For the list you need a list adapter. If you use a `ListActivity` it might look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ...
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    m.put("image", R.drawable.some_image);
    m.put("text", "Test");
listData.add(m);
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, 
            listData, R.layout.row_layout,
        new String[] {"image", "text"},
        new int[] {R.id.image, R.id.text});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The ArrayList contains all data for the list. Every row is represented by a HashMap and the keys of the data have to be equal to the ids where you want to display them. In the adapter you say that the key image is mapped to your ImageView and so on.